# Finding the dependence of dephasing time on flux noise in Transmon Qubits

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-computer, decoherence, noise

Before introducing some relevant concepts I'll begin by stating my question. What I am looking for is the connection between the noise the flux through the SQUID in my transmon qubit (related to the noise in the voltage sent down the flux line), and the dephasing rate of the qubit. More specifically, I want to find how the power spectral density of the flux is related to the dephasing rate $T_\phi$ of the transmon qubit (where $\frac{1}{T_2}=\frac{1}{2T_1}+\frac{1}{T_\phi}$).

So to begin with, lets look at the diagram of a Transmon qubit. It can be represented as
[image]

The circuit of the transmon shares the same topology as the circuit of a Cooper pair box, consisting of two superconducting islands coupled by two Josephson junctions. The coupling to ground is purely capacitive. The use of two Josephson junctions allows for tuning of the effective Josephson energy via the external magnetic flux penetrating $\Phi$ the superconducting loop. This is crucial; it is this flux that I am talking about above. It is controlled using a fluxline which we send a voltage over.

Similar to the Cooper Pair Box, the circuit provides no external
connection between the two islands and the operator for the
charge difference $N$ between the two islands has a discrete
spectrum, and the superconducting phase difference $phi$ is only defined modulo $2\pi$ i.e. it is a compact variable for which $\phi$ and $\phi+2\pi z$ are considered as identical for any integer z.

The corresponding Hamiltonian is given by
$H = 4 E_c (\hat{N}-n_g)^2 - E_j \hat{\cos{\phi}}$ where the two terms describe the contribution from
charging effects and Josephson tunneling, respectively and both $E_c$ and $E_j$ are constants. Important is that $\phi = 2\pi \frac{\Phi}{\Phi_0}$.

Now, as you might know the main benefit of using a transmon qubit is that it is highly insensitive to charge noise; there are many papers that cover this extensively, going into nice derivations showing that this is true. What I want to find however, is how the transmon reacts to noise in $\Phi$. More specifically, I want to relate the pure dephasing time $T_\phi$ ($\frac{1}{T_2}=\frac{1}{2T_1}+\frac{1}{T_\phi}$ to the power spectral density $S_{\Phi \Phi}(\omega)$. In principle this sensitivity is not an issue in daily operation; I however want to control $T_\phi$ so that I can let it vary over a wide range of values using different types of noise, so that's why I am interested in this.

Now, for this I suppose it is easiest to restrict ourselves to the two level system of the ground state and the first excited state, defining our qubit. The dephasing rate should then be related to the fluctuations in the transition energy $\omega_{10}$, so I suppose I have to find how this splitting depends on the applied flux. At this stage I am however getting a little bit lost, and I am not so sure on how to continue, so any advice on how to proceed would be much appreciated. I suppose I'll have to introduce fluctuations, relate them to autocorrelation functions and then to power spectral densities, but I can't seem to get that on paper.